# Center div (height) that have an autoincrement function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that autoincrement div height when any checkbox is checked and decrease height when is unchecked, but I would like to center vertically the div in the screen when increase or decrease his height, how can i do for that ?

Thanks for your help !

http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/6adby/

```
    $(function () {
      $(':checkbox').click(function() {

       $(".scroll").show();

       var delta = $(this).is(':checked') ? -1 : 1;

       if(delta < 0){
        $("#scroll").append( "<h2>" + $(this).next("label").html()  + "</h2>");
        $('.count').text(parseInt($('.count').text()) - 1);
      }
      else{
        $("#scroll h2:contains('" + $(this).next("label").html() + "')").remove();
        $('.count').text(parseInt($('.count').text()) + 1);
      }

      if ($(".count").text() == "0") {
        var children = $('.options').children('input:not(:checked)');
        for(var i= 0; i<children.length; i++) {
          $(children[i]).prop('disabled', true);
        }
      } else {
        var children = $('.options').children('input:not(:checked)');
        for(var i= 0; i<children.length; i++) {
          $(children[i]).prop('disabled', false);
        }
      }

      if ($(".count").text() == "18") {
        $(".scroll").hide();
      }

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set top to 50% and then on every addition recalculate the margin-top to be -height/2

```
top:50%
```

and then on your method set

```
var scroll=$('#scroll');
scroll.css('margin-top',(Math.ceil(scroll.height()/-2)+'px'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6adby/14/